# Average number of spin up particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

In a paramagnetic system, where $N = N_\uparrow + N_\downarrow$ is fixed, how does one calculate the average number of spin-up particles $\langle N_\uparrow \rangle$?

You can assume we have the canonical partition function. The Hamiltonian for this system is:

$$ H = \sum_{i=1}^N {\frac{(p_i - b s_i)^2}{2m} - h s_i} $$

where $s_i = +1$ for spin-up and $s_i = -1$ for spin-down.

How do I actually go about calculating this?

I know, in general for an operator $O$:

$$\langle O \rangle = \sum_{\mu} P_\mu O_\mu = \frac{1}{Z} \sum_{\mu} O_\mu e^{-\beta E_\mu}$$

Can someone show me how to explicitly use the Hamiltonian to evaluate this? Also, can we use $\langle N_\uparrow \rangle$ to evaluate $\langle N_\uparrow - N_\downarrow \rangle$? Can you just say $\langle N_\uparrow - N_\downarrow \rangle = 2\langle N_\uparrow \rangle - \langle N \rangle = 2\langle N_\uparrow \rangle - N$ since $N$ is fixed?

Comment: What do you get for $Z$ and $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial h}$ ?

Comment: Re your last question, what you propose is correct. $\langle N_\uparrow - N_\downarrow \rangle$ does equal $2\langle N_\uparrow \rangle - N$, for precisely that reason.

Comment: Thank you lionelbrits and Emilio!

Is $\frac{ \partial Z}{\partial h}$ related to $\langle N_\uparrow \rangle$ somehow? I'd like to find an expression for $\langle N_\uparrow \rangle =$ ... that I can use to calculate assuming we know the partition function.

Comment: Since this is tagged homework, I'll just say what do you get when you take $\frac{\partial H}{\partial h}$.

Comment: You get $+s_i$ or $-s_i$, i.e. $\pm$1 depending on if it is spin-up or spin-down. Could you be more direct as to what the relationship of $\frac{\partial H}{\partial h}$ and $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial h}$ is to $\langle N_\uparrow \rangle$? This is the part that is confusing me.

Comment: I may be barking up the wrong tree, since my stat mech is rusty, but $\frac{\partial H}{\partial h} = N_\downarrow - N_\uparrow$, and $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial h} = \beta \sum (N_\uparrow - N_\downarrow) e^{-\beta H}$. You can differentiate wrt $\ln Z$ too to get $Z$ in the denominator.

Since it's your calculation, I'll leave you to spot my mistakes, but that's the general idea of partition functions :)